# Bases local in topology

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if a point p has a finite local base *B*p, then it also has a local base consisting of only a set.

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: take the intersection of all of the finitely many elements in a base, it is open and it is minimal in the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the intersection of finitely many open sets is open. Let $U$ be the intersection of all of the finitely many sets in the basis. Then any open set containing the point contains $U$, so $\{U\}$ forms a basis at the point.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The intersection of finitely many open sets is open.